# Where are books stored after iBooks migration on Mavericks?

Tags: mac, books, macos

After upgrading to Mavericks all of my books from iTunes have been migrated to iBooks. They are no longer in my media library and I haven't been able to locate them as of yet. So where does iBooks store your books now?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

They are now buried inside the user Library folder.

The full path is:
`~/Library/Containers/com.apple.BKAgentService/Data/Documents/iBooks/Books`

The Books.plist there contains itemID values that connect the book titles with their *.epub or *.ibooks names [iBooks 1.2, OS 10.10.5].

Comment: Please, add that before copying the folder from mac A to mac B, one should kill `com.apple.BKAgentService` process on mac B (e.g. using Activity Monitor). Otherwise iBooks may not open.

Comment: Within that folder they can be tough to find because they all have big long UUIDs for names. Usually if you're trying to find the epub file it's probably to share it, or copy it to another device. I found that the easiest way for me to do so was just to drag the book from ibooks to a folder on my computer, and use it from there.