# Editing and syncing a pdf file on Mac and iPad through iBooks

Tags: ipad, data-synchronization, pdf, preview, books

I'd like to work on a draft pdf file on both a Mac and an iPad and see
the edits syncing invisibly in the background.

I create a new directory

```
mkdir ~/latex
```

and save the following latex in `~/latex/lipsum-novel.tex`

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```

then typeset it

```
pdflatex lipsum-novel
```

Now I have the pdf file `~/latex/lipsum-novel.pdf`

I drag that pdf file from Finder to the iBooks window, and from [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/106252/7985), we know that iBooks buries the pdf file in `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.BKAgentService/Data/Documents/iBooks/Books`

I'm guessing that I can now delete `~/latex/lipsum-novel.pdf`

```
rm ~/latex/lipsum-novel.pdf
```

All good. iBook took over the draft pdf. My objective now is to modify this
draft pdf on both OS X and on an iPad (with the modifications synced
in the background).

Before I even worry about syncing to iBooks on an iPad, I start by striking through some text.

[image: One strikethrough]

Already Preview warns me that (as with all OS X native files such as pdf files) "The original document can't be changed."

Fine. I save the modified file in `~/Documents/lipsum-novel copy.pdf`.

Now already iBooks has gone out of sync with Preview. If I exit iBooks and reload, I will be looking at the pdf file buried by iBooks, not on the file I edited. If I add a new strikethrough

[image: after two strikethroughs]

That hardly helps. I've just introduced yet a third pdf file.

How do I get iBooks to save my edits in its own copy (and sync it with an iPad).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that only synchronizing the original, pristine copy of a pdf file is supported. Synchronizing edits is not implemented, or at least [similar questions](https://discussions.apple.com/message/25410359#25410359) on discussions.apple.com remain unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to go into Library/Containers to get to iBooks, you can just drag the PDF file onto the iBooks window. You can then delete the old one

Comment: Yes, I know. The trouble is that after double-clicking on the icon of the pdf file inside iBooks, I am unable to edit the file and keep it inside iBooks. The copy pdf file that I save (in ~/Documents, i.e. without attempting to save deep inside ~/Library/Containers) remains external to iBooks. iBooks does not know the edits, and hence cannot sync them to iOS.